# Staticfiles don't load when deploying django app with prefix

Tags: python, django, wordpress, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy django application together with wordpress under the same domain. Django app should be under a suburl: "domain.com/djangoapp". I tried to set SCRIPT_NAME variable to that prefix in nginx conf file as well as in django settings.py. It worked and django app can be accessed under /djangoapp url, but staticfiles don't load.

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com   www.domain.com;

    root /var/www/domain.com/htdocs;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    include  common/redis.conf;
    include common/wpcommon.conf;

    location /static {
        root /home/user/project;
    }

    location /djangoapp/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/project.sock
        proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /djangoapp;
    }
}
```

and settings.py:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/djangoapp'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Also I tried to deploy django app on a separate domain and there staticfiles do load. The configs were the same except SCRIPT_NAME parts.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Comment: Of course. Nginx settings points to the directory created by `collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like staticfiles didn't load because of missed `/` in location path. Or maybe I made some typo in path to static directory.

I changed location to:

```
location /static/ {
        root /home/user/project;
    }
```

and now staticfiles work.

Comment: Congratulations! =)